# pg_dump taking lot of time for tables with TOAST entries

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

We are using Azure Postgresql Single Server(Postgresql on Windows). Some particular tables use TOAST as it stores an XML blob.

We are seeing `pg_dump` take a lot of time (~8 hours) to export few gigabytes (~100 GB) of data. We're using the command

```
pg_dump -Fd -v -d dbname -f /mnt/dbdump/dbdump -j 32
```

Export of all tables get completed except two tables that contain `TOAST` data. In terms of size, these tables represent only one-tenth of the total storage of the database.

What can we do to export these tables containing `TOAST` faster? We also tried `vacuum` before taking a dump on these tables but that helped only marginally.

Comment: There should be no specific performance problems with TOAST. Try and find the bottleneck; perhaps it is I/O speed.

Comment: Monitor with your system tools, like `top`, `vmstat`, etc.  Does the limit seem to be CPU, disk, something else, etc.?

Comment: Apart from the first few minutes, both I/O and CPU percentage ranged between 5-10%. All other tables (around 17k) had completed copying in less than an hour whereas these tables with TOAST entries lingered on for way longer. I don't have enough visibility on the instance itself since it's a managed database by Azure.